# How to convert a python regexp to java

Tags: java, python, regex

I need to convert the following python regexp to java regexp:

```
regexp = re.compile(r"^(?P<prefix>(%s)(%s)?)\s?\b(?P<name>.+)" %
                                ("|".join(array1),
                                 "|".join(array2)), re.IGNORECASE
                                                             | re.UNICODE)
```

where array1 and 2 are arrays of strings.

What I did is:

```
String regexp = String.format("^(?<prefix>(%s)(%s)?)\\s?\\b(?<name>.+)", array1, array2);
regexpPattern = Pattern.compile(regexp, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

But I get a PatternSyntaxException: "Unknown look-behind group near" in the question mark of (%s)(%s)**?**

I don't understand very well this question mark.

Any suggestion on how to translate it into Java 1.6?

Comment: Hint: the python syntax makes use of named capture groups.  If you _understand_ what the python regex does, you should be able to translate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tons of things will go wrong for you.

The `(?<` is a positive look-behind expression in java.

`(?P<prefix>` is a named group in python, there are no named groups in java.

`String.format` for `%s` and an array will not produce `|` joined strings from array like you do in python example.

First you will need to join strings by `|` from arrays manually.
Then when you have two strings, you can do:
`regexpPattern = Pattern.compile(String.format("^((?:%s)(?:%s)?)\\s?\\b(.+)", string1, string2));`

What was `prefix` group in python is now group 1 in java and `name` group is group 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly now! OK, named groups don't exist in java. After the pattern compilation, I use the replaceAll function calling the named groups by $1 and $2. And yes, I need to concat my arrays of strings. Thanks for your useful help.

Comment: `there are no named groups in java.` Nonsense. `(?<name>regex)` works fine in Java as named group, but it was introduced in Java 7. `(?<=...)` or `(?<!...)` are look-behind (positive and negative).