# Convert a python regexp to java

Tags: java, python, regex

I know it has already been asked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604709/how-to-convert-a-python-regexp-to-java) however I would like to use named group in java like Pshemo suggested and I can't figure what's wrong with my regex conversion:

Here is the python regexp:

```
regexp = re.compile(r'(?P<delim>[^\w\n"\'])(?P<space> ?)(?P<quote>["\']).*?(?P=quote)(?P=delim)', re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
matches = regexp.findall(content)
```

Here is my java converted regexp:

```
String regexp = "(?<delim>[^\\w\\n\\\"'])(?<space> ?)(?<quote>[\\\"']).*?(?=quote)(?=delim)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp, Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the issue? Note you converted named backreferences into positive lookaheads (`(?P=quote)` => `(?=quote)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You converted named backreferences into positive lookaheads (`(?P=quote)` => `(?=quote)`), while you need `\k<groupname>`:

```
String regex = "(?<delim>[^\\w\n\"'])(?<space> ?)(?<quote>[\"']).*?\\k<quote>\\k<delim>";
```

Tested at [OCPSoft regex tester](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, It seems to work way better than this way. It is supposed to catch the content of a line like ```"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"```. However I do not understand why it doesn't work if the spaces between the elements are removed: ```"one","two","three","four","five"```. The group spaces should match the space character 0 or 1 time, why isn't it matching when there are 0 spaces ?

Comment: You need to make the `delim` optional, `(?<delim>[^\w\n"']?)(?<space> ?)(?<quote>["']).*?\k<quote>\k<delim>` as the string starts with a quote.